# Как работает аннотация Inject в данном примере?

Tags: java, android, mvp, dagger2

Во время изучения библиотеки `dagger2` столкнулся с проблемой - не могу понять как происходит и работает аннотация `inject` в данном [примере](https://adityaladwa.wordpress.com/2016/05/11/dagger-2-and-mvp-architecture/)
для `MainScreenPresenter.java`. (пример крайне простой и если вы знакомы с `dagger2` и использованием его в андроиде то я уверен, у вас не составит труда взглянув сказать что к чему)

Можно увидеть, что зависимость объявляется на уровне конструктора:

```
@Inject
public MainScreenPresenter(Retrofit retrofit, MainScreenContract.View mView) {
    this.retrofit = retrofit;
    this.mView = mView;
}
```

Но в единственном месте использования данного класса процедура инициирования происходит одной строкой

```
@Inject
MainScreenPresenter mainPresenter;
```

Не понимаю - откуда в данном месте появляется при инициализации `MainScreenPresenter` берутся ссылки для `Retrofit retrofit` и `MainScreenContract.View mView` если они ни где не объявлены, и в компонентах и модулях нет связи с presenter'ом для предоставления связи?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dagger ищет зависимости в ваших компонентах, в данном случае `Retrofit` находит в `NetComponent`, а `MainScreenContract.View` в `MainScreenComponent`.
То же самое происходит когда методу, который провайдит например `Retrofit` добавить параметры

```
  @Provides
  @Singleton
  Retrofit provideRetrofit(Gson gson, OkHttpClient okHttpClient) {
      Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
              .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
              .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
              .baseUrl(mBaseUrl)
              .client(okHttpClient)
              .build();
      return retrofit;
  }
```

`Gson` и `OkHttpClient` `dagger` попытается найти в доступных компонентах.